# Add template file in admin edit form

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2, edit-form

I want to add `phtml` file in Grid\Edit which is contain image or other html part

Following `Form.php` file

```
<?php

namespace Vandor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config;
class Form extends Generic
{
    protected $systemStore;
    protected $wysiwygConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Config $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                'method' => 'post'
            ]
            ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('namegrid');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Detail'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'title',
                'label' => __('Title'),
                'id' => 'title',
                'title' => __('Title'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $wysiwygConfig = $this->wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['tab_id' => $this->getTabId()]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'content',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'content',
                'label' => __('Content'),
                'style' => 'height:36em;',
                'required' => true,
                'config' => $wysiwygConfig
            ]
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
    public function getFormHtml()
    {
        $html = $this->setTemplate('Vandor_Namespace::grid/image.phtml')->toHtml();
        $html .= parent::getFormHtml();

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Its show top of the main container.
Which is better way to add `phtml` in between form container

Comment: you just want to add images right???
you can do it by using by creating custom field type

Comment: @jigsparmar i want to add html elements

Comment: i add answer please check.it work for me in my custom extension

Answer (score 1):

To add Image In Edit form You need to add new Type

add below code in your Form.php file

```
$fieldset->addType(
            'thumbnail',
            '\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Proindex\Edit\Renderer\Thumbnail'
        );
```

And in that Renderer.php file

you can write below code

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Proindex\Edit\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

class Thumbnail extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    protected $blockdata;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Factory $factoryElement,
    CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
    Escaper $escaper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->blockdata = $blockdata;
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($factoryElement,$factoryCollection,$escaper);
    }

    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        // here you can write your code.
        $html = '';
        if ($this->getValue()) 
        {
            $html = '<p>simple text.</p>';

        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: how add `phtml` file in your code ?

Comment: i add Block file you can write code there

Comment: Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Proindex\Edit\Renderer\Thumbnail

Comment: Didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it's worked for me.

You can call other Block also by using this function if you want to add phtml file.

```
public function getFormHtml()
{
    $html = parent::getFormHtml();
    $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Digicel\IBAN\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\IbanEditBlock'
    )->toHtml();
    return $html;
}
```

IbanEditBlock.php

```
<?php

namespace Digicel\IBAN\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab;

class IbanEditBlock extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    const IBAN_TEMPLATE = 'customer/ibanform.phtml';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array                                 $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Set JS template to itself.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate(static::IBAN_TEMPLATE);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add in same edit form